# ¿ por que no se me imprimen todos los resultados?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un foreach para iterar unos arreglos pero al hacerlo e insertarlo en el HTML, solo me muestra el ultimo, el foreach que solo me muestra el ultimo es el de platforms y lo agrego al li, quisiera saber en que estoy fallando

```
function consultarApi(url) {

    fetch(url)
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
        .then(datos => mostrarResultados(datos));
}

function mostrarResultados(datos) {


    setTimeout(() => {
        spinner.remove
    }, 10000)
    spinner.remove();
    limpiarHTML();
    const titulo = document.querySelector('.titulo');
    const { seo_h1, results, next, previous, genres } = datos;
    titulo.textContent = seo_h1;
    resultado.appendChild(titulo)

    results.forEach((juego) => {



        const { background_image, name, rating, platforms, metacritic } = juego;
       
        platforms.forEach((plataforma) => {
            console.log(plataforma.platform.name);
             plataformas = plataforma.platform.name;
            

        })

        const card = document.createElement('div');
        card.classList.add('card');
        card.innerHTML = `

        <div class="imagen__card">
            <img src="${background_image}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="nombre__card">
            <h2>${name}</h2>
            <span class="meta">${metacritic}</span>
            <li class="plataformas">${plataformas}</li>
        </div>
        `;



        contenedor.appendChild(card)
        resultado.appendChild(contenedor);

       

    });
```

Y solo me arroja el ultimo como ya lo mencione
[image: resultaod]

Comment: Estás haciendo `plataformas = plataforma.platform.name;` y eso asigna a la variable. No estás concatenando ni armando un array en ninguna parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que no estás concatenando la variable existente a la nueva en el proceso del foreach, el código debería ser `plataformas += plataforma.platform.name;`

Aqui el codigo segun tu pregunta formulada:

```
function consultarApi(url) {

    fetch(url)
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
        .then(datos => mostrarResultados(datos));
}

function mostrarResultados(datos) {


    setTimeout(() => {
        spinner.remove
    }, 10000)
    spinner.remove();
    limpiarHTML();
    const titulo = document.querySelector('.titulo');
    const { seo_h1, results, next, previous, genres } = datos;
    titulo.textContent = seo_h1;
    resultado.appendChild(titulo)

    results.forEach((juego) => {



        const { background_image, name, rating, platforms, metacritic } = juego;
       
        platforms.forEach((plataforma) => {
            console.log(plataforma.platform.name);
             plataformas += plataforma.platform.name;
            

        })

        const card = document.createElement('div');
        card.classList.add('card');
        card.innerHTML = `

        <div class="imagen__card">
            <img src="${background_image}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="nombre__card">
            <h2>${name}</h2>
            <span class="meta">${metacritic}</span>
            <li class="plataformas">${plataformas}</li>
        </div>
        `;



        contenedor.appendChild(card)
        resultado.appendChild(contenedor);

       

    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, es que no entiendo la sintaxis **+=**

Comment: @KEVINSANTIAGOSARMIENTOGOMEZ En este Link tienes todos los operadores y sus usos https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators